# /data partition corrupted?

Tags: cyanogenmod, unbricking, partitions, samsung-galaxy-mini

I have a Galaxy Mini GT-S5570 running CM 10.1 which was installed about a month back. Yesterday my phone suddenly crashed and after rebooting it got stuck in a boot loop. I tried wiping the cache and data but when the CM recovery starts formatting /data partition it gets stuck. I also did a clean install of GingerBread stock ROM but the problem still persists. Formatting /data partition cannot be done after installing stock ROM also. Did I brick my phone? Can someone give me links where I can download new kernels and fix the problem?

Comment: If you really talk about *formatting* (and not simply *wiping*) which fails, I'm afraid that might rather be a hardware issue, and the memory chip got corrupted.

Comment: Yup I tried formatting usingCWM recovery. And every time I try to format the /data partition the phone hangs. I installed stock ROM and tried factory reset and even then the phone hangs when it starts formatting /data partition. So does that mean that the hardware is messed up?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but to me that sounds like trouble with the equivalent to "bad blocks", so formatting gets stuck due to write errors/locks or the like (I'm not that deep into low-level storage modifications). If you can watch `logcat` parallel to that process (e.g. using `adb logcat` while in CWM), that might give you some additional clues.

Answer (score -3):

its a kernel corruption. Just install a new kernel.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Both the CM kernel and the original kernel were working at one point, why would a third be better?